# How to enable contrib modules on Heroku Postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to use contrib modules in the new Postgres 9 shared databases on Heroku. More specifically, the **pg_trgm** and **fuzzystrmatch** modules. In the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/full-text-search) it says

> In addition, many complimentary extensions are available such as
>   fuzzystrmatch, pg_trgm, and unaccent.

I can't seem to find any documentation on HOW to actually enable these modules on a shared Heroku database. *See answer below.*

**NOTE:**

I tried adding them by connecting to the database with

```
heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN
```

and running

```
create extension pg_trgm
create extension fuzzystrmatch
```

but after trying to use it with

```
SELECT levenshtein('tests', 'test');
```

it still said

```
ERROR:  function levenshtein(unknown, unknown) does not existLINE 1: SELECT levenshtein('tests', 'test');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Anybody know why this happens?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648774/how-to-use-postgres-extensions-on-heroku-and-how-to-handle-their-migrations) while scouring Stack Overflow. Don't know why it didn't come up in any of my Google searches. Going to leave the question here if anybody else uses the same wording to search for this.

To enable modules, you need to add them to a migration as follows:

```
def up
  execute "create extension fuzzystrmatch"
  execute "create extension pg_trgm"
end
```

Comment: Note: You have to be on postgresql 9.1 for this to work.  To upgrade from an older version do the following: dev (https://gist.github.com/2883249), prod (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-postgres-versions)

Comment: You can get a full listing of the available extensions on Heroku Postgres with `echo 'show extwlist.extensions' | heroku pg:psql` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search

Answer (score 7):

In newer versions of Rails it should be sufficient to do:

```
def change
  enable_extension "fuzzystrmatch"
  enable_extension "pg_trgm"
end
```

If you need to write `up` and `down` methods, the corresponding method to `enable_extension` is `disable_extension`.